# icon of form input disappear when focus

Tags: html, css, forms, focus

I want to design a form input with icon inside of it.
when I click on this form element(:focus) then that icon is getting disappear and I want icon to be visible all the times.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            html,body {height: 100%;}
            input {
                width: 400px ;
                height: 4em;
                border: none ;
                padding: 1em 0 1em 2em ;
                color: black;
                background: url('https://www.bluebadgeinsurance.com.au/wp-content/uploads/multi-user-icon.png') left center no-repeat ;
                background-size: 30px 30px ;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
        </form>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm not showing the icon going away on focus. However, it is going away when I type a value into the form - is this what you are talking about? If so, this cannot be fixed because a value changes the form. You would need to place the image *outside* the form.

Answer (score 0):

looks like its a problem with 'live server' from vs-code and without live server there is no problem.

Comment: You should mark this as the solving answer to close the question.